# Searching for "all" "rented for 0.99" on iTunes Store API?

Tags: itunes, search, shortcuts-app

So, I've been trying to figure out how to replicate 99rental.com behaviour (it fishes the "0.99$ rental of the week" for the U.S. iTunes Store) for the Finnish iTunes Store.

So far I've gotten up to here:

`https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=FI&entity=movie&trackRentalPrice=0.99000&term=`

So, I do a search with the term `country=FI` (looking from Finland), with the term `entity=movie` (I'm looking for movies, that's for sure), the `trackRentalPrice=0.99000` (for some reason this is what I need to look for to get the rental price of 0.99), and then.. then nothing happens unless I write something like `term=heist` (since this week's iTunes 0.99€ rental is a film with the name `heist` on it). If there is no `term` added into the mix, I'll get this as a result:

`{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}`

If I on the other hand write in `term=heist` I'll get 11 results, one of which has the `"trackRentalPrice":0.99000` . So feels like not only do I need to put "something" in as a term, to even get a result, the second feels is that my `trackRentalPrice=0.99000` is completely ignored.

So, what am I doing wrong? I've tried to do the same query with `trackRentalPrice="0.99000"`, I've tried `trackRentalPrice="0,99000"`, I've tried `trackRentalPrice=0,99000` all to no avail.

Please help?

Btw, not looking to recreate 99rental for the Finnish iTunes Store, just want a result I could use in a Shortcut shortcut.

Comment: `trackRentalPrice` doesn't look like [a documented query param](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searching), and I don't see a relevant param for it (and `term` is described as a required param)?    Are you just assuming since it's in the response object, you can use it as a search param?

Comment: For those voting to close this as off-topic due to software development, this question is about using the Shortcuts app.  This, I believe, was [already discussed](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3372/88313) on the Meta site.

Comment: @ernie sure - i was hoping since it shows in the results that it can be searched for. i guess i was mistaken :'(